# How can I disable auto-dimming of the screen?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, screen-brightness

**What I'd like to see:**

- When idling, the screen turns off after the configured amount of time.

**What I see:**

- When I don't do anything, the screen dims a bit after ~23 seconds, then at 30 seconds it turns off as expected.

I have no idea why this dimming short before the screen timeout happens and where to disable it.

**My settings:**

- *Automatic Brightness* disabled, brightness set to the lowest level.
- *Screen time-out* at 30 seconds.
- *Auto adjust screen power* disabled.
- *Timeout* for lock screen is zero (*Immediately*).
- *Use Power saving mode* is enabled (it sets the screen brightness to 10% at less than 20% battery power left). Disabling it had no effect.

This happens with Android 2.3.6 (no idea if it worked before the update).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's to alert you that the screen's about to turn off.  It's more useful when your timeout is longer than 30 seconds, certainly.  I would assume you'd need a custom kernel or at least to root and edit some config files in order to prevent this, I don't believe there's anything in Settings for it.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest the [Screen On app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.androiddev.ScreenOn). I use it when I don't want the screen to dim or turn off, because I want to be able to instantly pause the playback on my audiobook without having to first hit the power button,then swiping the screen.

When you want it to  revert to a more power-saving mode, you can turn the app off again from the notification bar. It isn't customizable to allow it to dim after a specified time, but it will keep it from dimming at all. Better than nothing!

Comment: You should read again the question.